# Does this indicate two of my drives have bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, smartctl

Looking at smartctl output on 4 drives. Does this indicate a fatal error? Should I just replace the drives?

sdd1:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
 
1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     29911         4026536656
```

sdf1:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
 
1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     29952         74957
```

sda1:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
 
1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     40125         -
```

sdc1:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
 
1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     40136         -
```

Answer (score -1):

"Read failure" means that a sector on each disk has failed in a hard enough
manner that the disk firmware could not salvage its contents and map it to
a healthy spare sector.

A few such errors on a disk do not mean that the disk is failing.
It all depends on the number of the failed sectors and whether the
situation is stable (meaning if new sectors are failing).

To survey the state of your disks, use a command such as:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Of particular interest in the report is the part that comes after the text
"Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds".

I suggest that you run the above command for the two disks that show errors
and include the output in your post
([Edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1722452/edit)),
if you wish us to give our opinion.
For an example output see
[SMART Attributes documentation](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_Attributes_documentation).